# Windows 10 complete failure of right click capability

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade, right-click, mouse-click

I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10 about a month ago.  It is a 32 bit version and the right click was working everywhere, desktop icons, taskbar icons, the desktop itself and inside any browser.

All of a sudden, seems right around the end of the month before you can't revert the upgrade, there is no ability to right click anywhere, no menus come up, no indication that it is even attempting to connect.  What the heck happened and how do I get it back?

One more note, what I am getting sometimes, but only on the taskbar is the white context label with the icon name.  There was a point where double right clicking would give some menus on the taskbar icons but now that isn't working either.  And no the Right mouse button is not set up as the primary.

I have been flailing through all of the suggestions on the web that I can find with no luck whatsoever.

Thoughts, suggestions, HELP!

Comment: Have you tried another mouse? Do you have a [menu key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) on your keyboard? If so does that work?

Comment: I've seen a similar issue with a laptop (trackpad left mouse button stopped working).  It could be temporarily cured by plugging in then removing a USB mouse, and was permanently fixed by reinstalling Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center.

Comment: David,  You know sometimes the forest and the trees........ Looks like the mouse was the problem after all, a PS/2 adapter combination that had shorted a pin.  Just enough to make everything else seem to work correctly but not really.  DUH!!  Rule number 1, try the simple things first.  Say goodbye to the adapter and hello to a new mouse in a freed up USB port.   Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems right clicking with my laptop's touchpad (in Windows 10) so I remapped my caps lock key so that it opens the right-click menu.

I opened regedit, 
navigated to:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout

Then i modified a key called Scancode Map so that it has the value:
00000000 00000000 02000000 5DE03A00 00000000

If the Scancode Map key is not there it may be necessary to create it. Mine is of the type REG_BINARY.

Then reboot. I probably should have backed up the registry first, right?

I learnt all this primarily by relying on:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/

and then i searched around trying to find the code for the menu key

BTW,
3A00 represents the tab key, and 5DE0 represents the menu i.e. right-click key. Thus you can remap other keys if you want, by using the howtogeek guide.